# Downloadable products in Magento

Tags: magento, export-to-csv

Downloadable products in Magento: export CSV does not content download link and sample link? How to get in exported CSV?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer on this. Magento's CSV import/export does not support the download link in that way. I wrote a [lengthy blog post](http://www.ceilicornelison.com/blog/programmatically-associate-magento-downloadable-products-with-their-files/) on it over the weekend that should help you out quite a bit.